# Subspace $U$ of Vector Space $V$ $T$-cyclic and $T$-nondecomposable for diagonalizable $T\implies$ $U$ eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Say we're given a *diagonalizable* endomorphism $T: V \to V$, $V$ an $n$-dimensional Vectorspace over some Field $F$. Let $U \subsetneq V$ be T-cyclic with generator $u \in U$. Furthermore while $U$ is $T$-cyclic, it is not decomposable into proper $T$-cyclic subspaces. I want to prove that $U$ is an eigenspace. (I suspect it is a 1-dimensional Eigenspace).I'm not sure how to proceed. It is easy to show the other direction (any (must it be 1-dimensional? I suspect yes, but not sure) eigenspace is $T$-cyclic), but this direction is harder.

for emphasis:  the hypothesis is that while $U$ itself is $T$-cyclic, it is not decomposable into proper $T$-cyclic subspaces. Must $U$ then necessarily be an eigenspace (of dimension 1)?

Comment: Note that forcing $U \neq V$ doesn't really add anything as we can always embed a vector space into a larger one and extend $T$ to the larger space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can actually weaken the condition on $T$ to *triangulable*. Since $T$ is triangulable, the minimal polynomial $m_T$ of $T$ splits into linear factors over $F$. Let $p_u$ be the $T$-annihilator of $u$ and $\lambda$ be any root of $p_u$ so that $p_u(x) = (x-\lambda)q(x)$. (This is possible because $p_u$ must divide $m_T$, which splits.)  We now have 
$$p_u(T)u = (T-\lambda I)q(T)u=\vec{0}, \text{ but } q(T)u \neq \vec{0},$$
which implies $q(T)u$ is an eigenvector for $T$. Any eigenvector for $T$ generates a 1 dimensional $T$-cyclic subspace, but $U$ has no proper $T$-cyclic subspaces, so $U$ is a 1 dimensional eigenspace.